# Variable Not Working In While Loop

Tags: php, email, mysqli

I am sending a newsletter using the following code I am going to post. I have a `$to` variable that is for email addresses in my database. I use a while loop to send an email for each email address in my database to preserve privacy. At the bottom of the email I have a link for unsubscribing which is linked to a simple script that has the users email in the link. The `$to` variable is not working in the link though. The email sends but when I look to see if it sent all the data the link looks like `http://example.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?email=` instead of `http://example.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?email=example@email.com`.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here since I am getting no errors, and the script is working except for sending the email in the link.

```
require('/home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/settings/globalVariables.php');
require('/home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/settings/mysqli_connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($conn,"newsletterlist");
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsletterusers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$subject = str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", '%0A', '%0D'), '', $_POST['subject']);
$message = str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", '%0A', '%0D'), '', $_POST['body']);


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Jesse Elser<jesse@jollyrogerpcs.com>' . "\r\n";

if (!$result) exit("The query did not succeded");
else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $to = $row['email'];
        $date = date("m/d/Y h:i:sa");
        $body ='<!DOCTYPE HTML>';
        $body .='<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #000; color: #fff; text-align: center; font-family: verdana;">';
        $body .='<div id="container" style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; background-color: #121212;">';
        $body .='<div id="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6400;">';
        $body .='<img src="http://jollyrogerpcs.com/images/main/logo.png" width="100%">';
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='<div id="subject" style="background-color: #121212; text-align: center;">';
        $body .='<h1 style="color: #ff6400; margin: 0;">'.$subject.'</h1>';
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='<div id="message" style="background-color: #232323; color: #fff; padding: 10px;">';
        $body .=  $message;
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='<div id="footer" style="background-color: #121212; padding: 10px;">';
        $body .='<a href="http://jollyrogerpcs.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff6400;">Visit Our Site</a> | Thanks for subscribing to our newsletter! | <a href="http://jollyrogerpcs.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?email="'.$to.'" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff6400;">Unsubscribe</a> <br> E-mail sent: ';
        $body .= $date;
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='</body>';
        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Location: http://jollyrogerpcs.com/newsletter.php');
```

Comment: `$to` not `to`...see it? `/php/unsubscribe.php?email="'.to.'" `

Comment: Dang it lol I noticed that earlier and updated my code to get the same results. Let me update my question.

Comment: Wrote it as an answer below take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the `href` attribute before the email address is included so...

```
<a href="http://example.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?email="'.$to.'"
```

Should be

```
<a href="http://example.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?email='.$to.'"
```

As is it would render as

```
<a href="http://example.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?email=" email@address.com"....
```

Which would make the link `http://example.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?email=`.

Comment: That fixed it. I see what you meant now that it's visual :) Thanks.